# macOS Sierra Preview Extra Services

Tags: preview, services

When I highlight text and right click, I usually get this menu: [image]

Notice at the bottom where I have custom services such as "Custom Text To Speech" and "Add to iTunes as a Spoken Track". This use to also be available in Preview when I would read a pdf but now only this appears:

[image]

I need this feature for custom services I use but it seems to not be available in macOS Sierra's version of Preview.

Comment: How is the service programmed? Is it standalone, or was it created with Automator?

Comment: It is a Automator services but it other stock text services like "Summarize" and "Add to iTunes as a Spoken Track" also don't work. @tubedogg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very happy to report that upgrading from Sierra to High Sierra (macOS 10.13.2) reintroduced the text services in PDFKit and therefore Preview.app (Screenshot of a German macOS where "Preview" is "Vorschau" but you'll get the idea):

[image]

Classical Apple giveth, Apple taketh away and giveth again cycle I guess...

Maybe this also leads to a more functional PDFKit on iOS.

Cheers everyone

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the service in the keyboard system preferences, like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

macOS Sierra introduced a new PDFKit framework. The apps which are based on PDFKit do not support text services (the services which are only available when text is selected).

Preview, Skim, Safari's built-in PDF viewer, and Chrome's built-in PDF viewer all do not support text services.

Firefox's built-in PDF viewer supports text services, but you need access the service from menu bar (Firefox -> Services) after selecting some text.